# Error while creating XSD schema for specific XML format

Tags: xml, xsd

For the following XSD file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="stringtype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="inttype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="dectype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<!-- Tokens -->
<xs:complexType name="RelativeText">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="flow" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="amount" type="inttype"  use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="LineText">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="BoxText">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="dectype" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="height" type="dectype" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="dectype" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="dectype" use="required" />
</xs:complexType> 
<!-- Settings -->
<!-- Local Settings - per file type -->
<!-- Directories  -->
<xs:complexType name="MonitorDirectoryElementType">
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="OutputDirectoryElementType">
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="LoggingDirectoryElementType">
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="FileExtensionElementType">
    <xs:attribute name="extension" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="LocalSettingsType">
     <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="file-type" type="FileExtensionElementType" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="monitor-directory" type="MonitorDirectoryElementType" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="output-directory" type="OutputDirectoryElementType" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="log-directory" type="LoggingDirectoryElementType" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- Global Settings -->
<xs:complexType name="ApplicationLogFileType">
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="stringtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GlobalSettingsType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="log-file" type="ApplicationLogFileType" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- Token Type Wrap Around -->
<xs:complexType name="TokensType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="line-text" type="LineText" />
        <xs:element name="box-text" type="BoxText" />
        <xs:element name="relative-text" type="RelativeText" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- Template content -->
<xs:complexType name="templatecontenttype">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="local-settings" type="LocalSettingsType" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="tokens" type="TokensType" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- Main application settings -->
<xs:complexType name="ApplicationConfigurationType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="global-settings" type="GlobalSettingsType" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="template-content" type="templatecontenttype"  />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ApplicationConfiguration" type="ApplicationConfigurationType"  />
</xs:schema>
```

I want to be able to use with an xml like this:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
<ApplicationConfiguration>
    <global-settings >
        <log-file path="D:\applicationLog.log" />
    </global-settings>
    <template-content>
        <local-settings>
            <file-type extension=".txt" />
            <monitor-directory path="D:\monitor\"/>
            <output-directory path="D:\output"/>
            <log-directory path= "D:\ThisInstanceLogs"/>
        </local-settings>
        <tokens>
            <line-text name="xyz1" />
            <line-text name="xyz12" />
            <relative-text name="xyz123" flow="below" amount="1"/>
            <line-text name="xyz1234" />
            <line-text name="xyz12345" />
            <box-text name="thada" width="100" height="100" x="2" y="3"/>
        </tokens>
    </template-content>
</ApplicationConfiguration>
```

Where

- global-settings can appear only once
- template-content = unlimited times
- local-settings & tokens - once per each
- the elemens within tokens=unlimited in any order (even 0 occurences)
- log-file once & mandatory

  . I feel that I doing a lot of things wrong here ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've got an `xs:element` tag that isn't closed:

```
<xs:element name="LocalSettings" type="LocalSettingsType" maxOccurs="1">
```

I'm also seeing errors in this section:

```
<xs:complexType name="ApplicationConfigurationType">
    <xs:all >
        <xs:element name="global-settings" type="" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="template-content" type="templatecontenttype"  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

The *type* attribute shouldn't be empty, and *maxOccurs* must be 0 or 1 in an `xs:all` element group.

To match your requirements, I think the schema for that section should look something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="ApplicationConfigurationType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="global-settings" type="GlobalSettingsType" />
            <xs:element name="template-content" type="templatecontenttype"
              minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="template-content" type="templatecontenttype"
              maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element name="global-settings" type="GlobalSettingsType" />
                <xs:element name="template-content" type="templatecontenttype"
                  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

At the top level you have a choice - your first element will either be `global-settings` (the first sequence) or `template-content` (the second sequence).

If the first element is `global-settings`, then it can be followed with 0 or more `template-content` elements, and that's all there is to it.

If the first element is `template-content`, there can potentially be many of those (thus it's unbounded). And it can optionally be followed by a `global-settings` element (the nested sequence). If there is a `global-settings` element, then that may in turn be followed by 0 or more additional `template-content` elements.

I think this covers all possibilities. Both `global-settings` and `template-content` are optional. There can be at most one `global-settings` elements. And they can appear in any order.

Comment: yes, correct, I noticed now, I ws going to update my answer, still the question remains is my semantic ok in regards with what I what I want to achieve?

Comment: @A.K I'm not an expert on XML schemas, but it looks ok to me other than the `xs:all` on the *ApplcationConfigurationType* which is probably not what you want if you need to support multiple `template-content` elements. Also some of your element names don't match up with your actual XML, but I'm sure you'll spot those when you start validating.

Comment: It has validated now, after some modifications, now all that remains is the semantic ..

Comment: this one still remains: Additional information: Line: 22, Position: 3 "Element 'template-content' cannot appear more than once if content model type is "all"."
While trying to have multiple template-content, and I wnat just one global settings

Comment: @A.K I see you figured out the need for `xs:choice` instead of `xs:all`, but I think your attributes aren't quite right. What you have now allows multiple occurrences of `global-settings` which I don't think is what you want. I've updated my answer with what I think it should be. Although, looking at it again, I'm not sure mine is perfect either.

Comment: Yes of course, you are right, the schema does still validate the xml.

Comment: @A.K Updated my answer again with what I now think is the correct schema.